# Loading Hugo to GitHub Pages

Tags: github-pages, hugo, static-html

I am trying to upload a Hugo Theme to a Github pages and cannot figure out where I am going wrong. I have tried multiple different sites and methods and coming up blank. This is there I started https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/ and no luck there. I am getting a 404 - file not found error when trying to access the site from tangerine2003.github.io

Running the site on my local host works every time. Could someone look over the below and tell me what I am doing wrong?

https://github.com/tangerine2003/tangerine2003.github.io

Answer (score 2):

One possible issue is that your repository https://github.com/tangerine2003/tangerine2003.github.io is empty.

You need to make sure the step `git push origin master` mentioned in the ["Host on GitHub" Hugo page](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/) does execute successfully, in order for GitHub pages to have anything to publish.

---

Update: what I know see in the GitHub repo is an Hugo project *without* the `docs/` folder supposed to include the *built* HTML static pages.
The `docs/` folder is mentioned in "[Deployment of Project Pages from `/docs` folder on `master` branch](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#deployment-of-project-pages-from-docs-folder-on-master-branch)".

The [`config.toml`](https://github.com/tangerine2003/tangerine2003.github.io/blob/169b3ce5f1fc988819e6864fbd9b93720152668c/config.toml) does not include `publishDir = "docs"`, and you need to make sure your [GitHub repo is set to publish what is in `docs/`](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch).

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/select-master-branch-docs-folder-as-source.png]

In short: publishing the Hug project is not enough: you need to add, commit and push as well the pages built from that Hugo project.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is added now. I had it added yesterday but erased it in all my efforts to figure out why it will not post

Comment: @chrisclifton I have updated my answer to answer your updated question and address your current GitHub repository content.